# Checkbox control in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a gridview with checkbox control as a template field and one bounded field..
The grid is binded on every postback through a function and the grid contents remain the same on every post back..now when i check one of the checkboxes and then click the button at the end of the page, I need to store that particular row information..but I'm not able to retreive that information because when I check and then click button..the page loads and then the grid again populates and then checkboxes become uncheck and no CheckedChanged event fires..Help me with this
I need to persist the state of checkbox on every postback even when it is checked..how to do this??

Comment: Do you have to bind the grid on every postback?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible if you are using asp.net 4.0 using

```
<asp:GridView id="GridView2" runat="server" EnablePersistedSelection="true">
</asp:GridView>
```

If you are using 3.5, you will have to retain `checkbox` info in `viewstate`. I hope this will be helpful.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/202938/How-to-select-multiple-records-from-the-GridView-a

Another Option:

This is how msdn have described a hotmail type gridview.. may be this can help.. this will require you to extend existing GridView Control.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163612.aspx

Regards.

Comment: I am using asp.net 3.5 and i'm doing multiple postbacks to the server on several dropdownlist controls..now i want when i select some checkboxes from the grid and then click the button at the end ..the grid should appear to be checked for the selected ones after page_load but thisis not happening since on page_load the function which binds the data is called and the checkbox gets unchecked..i was thinking that its possible only when i do not do the post back and use javascript on grid control..

Comment: Ajax is an option but it will require change the way you currently handle events.. one thing to ask have you bind checkbox to some dataitem element? do you really need to databind checkbox?

Comment: please check i have added another option by extending gridview control.. hope that will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

In the `page_load` event function, please use the following code for your persistent data

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    //your static data
}
```

Comment: but the postback is happeneing multiple times and the grid should be visible on every postback..if I call my function which binds the data only on if(! IsPostBack) the grid will become invisible on later postbacks..

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem is fairly common. I haven't seen any "simple" solution yet, but here are 3 separate methods I have used. Each was used because of a limitation in the system.

**Solution 1**
Use AJAX. By putting your controls within an update panel, you can persist the changes by making them "real-time" in the database. This is not really a "simple" solution, but in my opinion it is one of the easiest to implement. Since the change is psuedo-immediate, there is no real need to worry about post-backs and persistence.

**Solution 2**
Use a "change management" control of sorts. You can apply a hidden control whose value is used to keep track of any changes made in relevant controls. You would need to devise a coherent data structure that provide at least a control ID and the new value (possibly the old value if you need some kind of "roll-back" feature). This would need to be coded in JavaScript so that any changes to the hidden control's value were structured and not duplicated. Then on your postback you would need to read this control's value, make any pertinent changes, and then rebind your data as appropriate. This can be fairly cumbersome, and it would need to be well-documented in the event that you pass this application on to a successor.

**Solution 3**
Use the PostBack for CheckChanged events and keep all data managed in the view state. During the RowItemCreated event of the GridView you can find the checkbox control in the relevant cell and manually add the delegate handler to that control to handle the postback in the event of a CheckChanged event firing. You can then have the change immediate. The drawback to this is that PostBack events become frequent and heavy. If you're storing large amounts of data in the ViewState this also causes page load to be slow and unresponsive, so whatever structure you choose for the ViewState you'll want to keep it small.